# multiple ingress are not working in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a problem with ingress, where I have multiple environments in my single kubernetes clustering... Now the problem is that if I have a single environment it works perfectly fine with below configuration, As soon as I deploy second envioronment and hit the ip of second environment, it is started pointing to first environment  even though service names are different

my first ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          backend:
            serviceName: servicetest-1
            servicePort: 1000
        - path: "/test"
          backend:
            serviceName: servicetest-1
            servicePort: 2000
```

my second ingress-resources:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          backend:
            serviceName: servicetest-2
            servicePort: 1000
        - path: "/test"
          backend:
            serviceName: servicetest-2
            servicePort: 2000
```

The catch is if I delete my ingress resources in first environment, second environment starts working fine.

Another point both of my ingress resources are deployed in the same namespace

is that something I need to do in annotations or re-directions

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Both `Ingress` have the same `name` and are in the same `namespace`. As the only difference between both ingress are `spec.rules.http.paths.backend.serviceName` and Name and Namespace stayed the same, Kubernetes overwritte previous config instead of create new resource.

`ingress.extensions/test-ingress configured`

You should change name of `ingress` resource.

Comment: my bad... actually it is different names... I wrongly mentioned

Comment: well okay i got it. you have multiple rules for same path in same host. "/" path has two rule. ingress picks firts rule by default i think.

Comment: @magic I think you should read about `Ingress Patch Matching`: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md and check some examples from `Path rewrite`: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

In NGINX, regular expressions follow a first match policy.

If you don't fully understand this, you should create a new question, as this answer was correct to information you have provided.